# Kafka - Sequential I/O

Tags: apache-kafka

I am going through some of the articles to better understand what could be the reasons why Kafka is faster compared with other Messaging systems

One of the reasons apart from Zero On Copy , is Sequential IO - this sounds exciting. However, some follow up question wrt it.

- Is the Sequential IO in all cases like seeking offset? In case of seeking offset, doesnt it involve some kind of random seek access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kafka, we generally seek offset during the consumer startup and every poll after that reads messages one after the other sequentially.

So, if seeking to an offset is random, it happens only during the startup and not afterwards i.e. it is only once. Subsequent polling is always sequential. So, it is only sequential access afterwards.

You may for example call `seek()` in your program multiple times but that is not what is used atleast in production. Because for getting records, you may any way have to `poll()` which always reads messages sequentially from the given offset.

Comment: please elaborate it "In Kafka, we generally seek offset during the consumer startup and every poll after that reads messages one after the other sequentially."

Comment: Yes, the first `seek` is random, we seek to a specific offset where we will specify offset from where we want to read messages *from* and then we call `poll()`. Now, `poll()` returns records from that offset one by one performing a sequential read. So `seek` is done once and after that it is all `poll()` i.e. `seek` is not done *often* as with databases.

Comment: understood, i mean would you mind elaborating it  how it happens with respect to segments and indices ?

Comment: first we have to find out the segment for the partition offset ; the log and index filename has start offset for segment, then the corresponding index file is looked for the given offset to get the physical location of the message in the log.